# divided power structure on Hocschild cohomology?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras

Does Hochschild cohomology of a cocommutative Hopf algebra over a field of positive characteristic have a natural divided power structure? 
If not, perhaps a certain natural extra structure on the Hopf algebra would yield one?